# rsync verify and delete

Tags: rsync

I would like to be able to transfer files from a camera memory card to my local storage, and once copied, verify that the files match between source and destination and then delete the files on the source.

Currently I am running:

`rsync --update -va --progress --no-r --info=progress2 source/** destination`

I am flattening the destination so only files get copied and not source directories.

What would I need to add to this command to then cleanup all files and directories from the source as long as the transfer is verified?

Answer (score 0):

`--remove-source-files`

I googled "rsync delete from source" and found this: [rsync delete files on sending side after transfer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24801243/4518341). And here's part of the description from [`man rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html#options):

```
--remove-source-files
       This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files 
       (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and
       have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.
```

Comment: Thanks ``@wjandrea`` but this only deletes the files not the directories. I effectively want to delete the directories. I suppose I could sting a non rsyn command ``rm-r``? for the source folder? I effectively want to format the volume again ready for the camera.

Comment: @ejnewman Oh, I missed that you want to delete the directories too. I think your answer has the best solution for that. :)

Comment: ``@wjandrea`` - great, that solves it then! thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work in the end with the following:

```
rsync --update -va --progress --no-r --remove-source-files --info=progress2 source/** destination &&
    find source -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

This will use rsync to clear the synced files and then another command to clear the empty directories of the source.